# How to call a method in another method

Tags: objective-c

I want to call a method from another method.
Fox example, I want to call dismissActionSheet in buttonPressed.
How to do that?

```
- (void)dismissActionSheet
{
    [menu dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    categoryButton.hidden=TRUE;
    categoryLabel.hidden=FALSE;

    NSString *selected=[categoryData objectAtIndex:0];
    categoryLabel.text=selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the current object with the keyword self.  To invoke dismissActionSheet simply call

```
[self dismissActionSheet];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed
{
    categoryButton.hidden=TRUE;
    categoryLabel.hidden=FALSE;

    NSString *selected=[categoryData objectAtIndex:0];
    categoryLabel.text=selected;
    [self dismissActionSheet]
}
```